# NodeJS and MariaDB. Avoid queries for every column

Tags: mysql, node.js, mariadb, sql-injection, handle

I'm using NodeJS and MariaDB. I have a lot of tables where some Users can change  a value via requests. I don't want to prepare queries for every column the user wants to update like:

```
module.exports.updateName = (name,id) =>{
    return pool.query("UPDATE Users SET name=? WHERE user_id=?;", [name,id])
}
module.exports.updateAge = (name,id) =>{
    return pool.query("UPDATE Users SET age=? WHERE user_id=?;", [age,id])
}
```

I want to build s.th. like a template which expects the table, columns and values.
In order to prevent SQL Injection attacks I'm already using the ? placeholders for the values. Unfortunately MariaDB doesn't support placeholders for identifiers like ??.
I don't feel safe to just concat the table name or the columns to the query string like:

```
"SELECT INTO " + tablename +"(" + columns + ")" ...
```

My idea was to query at every sever start, which table and column names exist in my database and store them in a list. Then i could check whether the passed table and column strings are valid or not.

Does this idea makes sense or is a common way? How would handle that problem?
I'm thankful for every advice!

Greetings

Comment: Construct the query with as many (or few) clauses the end-user needs.  Do it in application code, not SQL.

Comment: Can you give me an example?I don' get it what you mean

Answer (score 0):

Well, what I'd do is to create a stored procedure with params, user, column, value and inside it would decide what update statement to use, like so:

```
create procedure updateValues (in uid int, in columnid int, in value int)...
begin
    if columnid = 0 then
       update users set name = value;
    else if columnid = 1 then
       update users set age = value;
    end if
end
```

Comment: but what if the users let's say wants to update 4 columns with different values. I would have to call the procedure 4 times. That's not very efficient isn't it?

Comment: Well, are you planning to call the SP several times in a row? Otherwise it might not be significant. On the other hand, you can maybe assemble the SQL string and filter for attacks, by removing SQL statements and symbols...honestly is as much effort as keeping a list of valid columns and probably not as safe. The getter/setter encapsulation approach is to separate values, but you can also group them by using optional params in the sp

Comment: Forget I just realized MySQL doesn't support optionals...ok, so another option is to have the sp list all possible arguments, in order, and check against the list

Comment: Also, calling an sp offers some protection agains sql injection, because you have to prepare it and pass the parameters in ?, so extra sql code would likely cause an error. Still, look for filtering libraries, there might be something useful